# Linux - How to compare installed package version new install by shell script

Tags: linux, shell, centos, redhat, rpm

I am trying to write a shell script that can install an Avamar client onto a Redhat or Centos box. I place the pkg I want to install into a repo dir /ava/repo

The script needs to perform the following:

1. Check /ava/repo for latest pkg in there. In this case latest would be AvamarClient-linux-sles11-x86_64-6.1.100-802.rpm (edited)
2. Check the server for previous installed Avamar client. I can do the check with

   ## rpm -qa | grep AvamarClient

AvamarClient-6.1.100-402.x86_64

1. Once the version has been checked I need to compare that against the version I am installing. For example if the pkg I am adding (latest in /ava/repo) is AvamarClient-6.1.200-102.x86_64 I need to check this against AvamarClient-6.1.100-402.x86_6 and determine which is newer or if it is the same.

If the pkg I am trying to install is the same, output to a logfile that pkg is already installed and end

If the pkg I am trying to install is older, output to a logfile that pkg already installed is newer and end

If the pkg I am trying to install is newer, uninstall older pkg then install new pkg and output to logfile that package was upgraded then end

I only have basic shell skills so this task is proving tough for me! Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This shows you how to do text extractions and manipulation in quite a bit of detail. We will basically extract the versions from the candidate files in /ava/repo and convert them into a number that can be used for comparison using the formula:

```
AVAMAR_INSTALLED_MAGIC=$((1000000 * $AVAMAR_INSTALLED_VER_MAJ + 10000 * $AVAMAR_INSTALLED_VER_MIN + $AVAMAR_INSTALLED_VER_REL))
```

We will use this numerical form to first figure out the latest version we have in /ava/repo and then compare that to the version we have installed to see if we want to replace it.

So here we go:

### THIS IS COMPLICATED

First the whole thing:

```
AVAMAR_CANDIDATE=$(ls -1 /ava/repo/AvamarClient* |   \ 
           sed -e 's/.*/&:&/'                                       \
               -e 's/-[0-9]*-x86_64//1'                             \
               -e 's/AvamarClient-//'                               \
               -e 's/\./:/1' -e 's/\./:/1' |                        \
           awk -F: '{ print 1000000 * $1 + 10000 * $2 + $3 " " $4 }' | \
           sort -n | tail -n1 )
```

So let's look at what's happening. We assume that we have more than one copy of a candidate in the repo.

We list all the files in `/ava/repo` and pipe it to a sed + awk script that figures out their version numbers and sorts them so that the last one is the LATEST one.

Let's look at each part

### SED

step 1:

```
       -e 's/.*/&:&/'
```

Creates two copies of the name separated by a `:`. (We'll cut apart the first one and reduce it to just the version number using step 2 and 3. keep the second one intact for the rpm command to be used later)

step 2:

```
      -e 's/-[0-9]*-x86_64[^:]*//1'
```

get rid of the word `-NNN-x86_64.rpm` from the first copy of the file names to be precise get rid trailing bits leading up to the `:` we inserted in earlier (but not the colon).

step 3:

```
     -e 's/AvamarClient-//'
```

get rid of the word `AvamarClient-` from the first copy of the file names

step 4:

```
     -e 's/\./:/1' -e 's/\./:/1'
```

Converts the `.` in JUST the extracted version numbers to `:`

So for example:

```
     ls -1 /ava/repo/AvamarClient-6.4.200-400-x86_64.rpm  | sed -e 's/.*/&:&/' -e 's/-[0-9]*-x86_64[^:]*//1' -e 's/AvamarClient-//' -e 's/\./:/1' -e 's/\./:/1'
```

would output:

```
     6:4:200:AvamarClient-6.4.200-400-x86_64.rpm
```

### AWK

Now to convert the extracted version to something magical we push that through awk: where `-F:` splits the string above using : as the delimiter. So $1 = MAJ, $2 = MIN, $3 = REL, $4 = Filename; for example above it would be $1 = 6; $2 = 4; $3 = 200; $4 = AvamarClient-6.4.200-400-x86_64.rpm

So we apply our magic formula and print the filename in awk:

```
    '{ print 1000000 * $1 + 10000 * $2 + $3 " " $4 }'
```

so for above example it would output:

```
    6040200 AvamarClient-6.4.200-400-x86_64
```

And voila we have a magic comparable number

### SORT and TAIL

Since we may have more than one file in our repo, the above will be a list of them and because we have the magic number we can use it to get the latest one. Use `sort -n` to sort and use `tail -n1` to grab the very last one (sort is ascending order).

So now in AVAMAR_CANDIDATE we would have `6040200 AvamarClient-6.4.200-400-x86_64`

Let's make life easier and put this into two variables:

```
      AVAMAR_CANDIDATE_FILE=$(echo $AVAMAR_CANDIDATE | cut -f2 -d' ')
      AVAMAR_CANDIDATE_MAGIC=$(echo $AVAMAR_CANDIDATE | cut -f1 -d' ')
```

Let's do the same with the installed version:

```
AVAMAR_INSTALLED=$(rpm -qa | grep AvamarClient)

AVAMAR_INSTALLED_MAGIC=$(echo $AVAMAR_INSTALLED | \
      sed -e 's/^AvamarClient-//'  \ 
          -e 's/-[0-9].*x86_64$//' \
          -e 's/\./:/g' | \
      awk -F: '{ print 1000000 * $1 + 10000 * $2  + $3 }' )
```

Now all you have to do is compare the value of the two magic numbers:

```
if [ $AVAMAR_INSTALLED_MAGIC -lt $AVAMAR_CANDIDATE_MAGIC ] ; then
         rpm -ivU /ava/repo/$AVAMAR_CANDIDATE_FILE 
fi
```

I hope that this will get you to learn shell scripting as it is an amazingly powerful tool.

Answer (score -2):

You have to get the Major number, Minor number and Build number from the installed package.
Similarly you need to know the Major number, Minor number and Build number from the package you are trying to install.
Start with comparing the Major number and then Minor and then Build number

I have written the logic as i have explained

```
#!/bin/bash

INSTALLED_VERSION="AvamarClient-6.1.100-402.x86_64"
CURRENT_VERSION="AvamarClient-6.1.90-102.x86_64"

#get the Major numbe,Minor number and build number from the Installed version string
INST_MAJOR=`echo $INSTALLED_VERSION | cut -d'-' -f2 | cut -d'.' -f1`
INST_MINOR=`echo $INSTALLED_VERSION | cut -d'-' -f2 | cut -d'.' -f2`
INST_BUILD=`echo $INSTALLED_VERSION | cut -d'-' -f2 | cut -d'.' -f3`
echo "INST_MAJOR=$INST_MAJOR,INST_MINOR=$INST_MINOR,INST_BUILD=$INST_BUILD"

#get the Major numbe,Minor number and build number from the Current version string
CUR_MAJOR=`echo $CURRENT_VERSION | cut -d'-' -f2 | cut -d'.' -f1`
CUR_MINOR=`echo $CURRENT_VERSION | cut -d'-' -f2 | cut -d'.' -f2`
CUR_BUILD=`echo $CURRENT_VERSION | cut -d'-' -f2 | cut -d'.' -f3`
echo "CUR_MAJOR=$CUR_MAJOR,CUR_MINOR=$CUR_MINOR,CUR_BUILD=$CUR_BUILD"

if [ $CUR_MAJOR -gt $INST_MAJOR ]
then
    echo "Starting with Installation..."
elif [ $CUR_MAJOR -eq $INST_MAJOR ]
then
    if [ $CUR_MINOR -gt $INST_MINOR ]
    then
        echo "Starting with Installation..."
    elif [ $CUR_MINOR -eq $INST_MINOR ]
    then
        if [ $CUR_BUILD -gt $INST_BUILD ]
        then
            echo "Starting with Installation..."
        elif [ $CUR_BUILD -eq $INST_BUILD ]
        then
            echo "Package already installed..."
        else
            echo "You are trying to install older package...Exiting"
        fi
    else
        echo "You are trying to install older package...Exiting"
    fi
else
    echo "You are trying to install older package...Exiting"
fi
```

Comment: @LtWorf: First in case of the questioning fellow rpm versioning may not be smart enough to figure out the whether or not it should be replaced. Also this particular solution is ACTUALLY using  string comparison, so your comment is off base. String comparison CANNOT be used to actually do version comparisons like it's shown above so the solution above would fail on an example like:

6.4.200 and 8.0.300

because the logic of `elif` fails. So -1 on the solution and -1 on the comment

Comment: Why can't rpm figure it out? On debian dpkg can, so i suppose rpm should be similar.

Comment: dpkg --compare-versions 1.2-3 gt 1.1-4